# casting data from a loop to 2d array

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array of data to fetch from firebase, I'm making a for loop to iterate through the data in order to store it in a 2d array with 3 elements for each section ex: `[["1","2","3"],["4","5","6"],["7","8","9"]]`

How do I append to the array and store it as 2d array like the one above with 3 element in each array index ?

```
@State var array2d: [[]] 

    ForEach(Networking.forSalePosts){i in
//don't know how to append it here :)
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Show the code you have so far. You'll get much better responses that way

Comment: [Collection Types](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html) from the Swift Programming Language book and

Comment: It sounds like you should create an array of a custom class instead of a 2d array. This will be much easier (and safer) to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `forSalePosts` is a 1d array of `String`s, here is how you can achieve this using `reduce`, a higher-order function:

```swift
@State var array2d: [[String]] = []

array2d = Networking.forSalePosts.reduce(array2d) { previous, current in
    guard let last = previous.last else { 
        // first iteration, array2d is empty
        return [[current]] 
    }

    if last.count == 3 {
        // start new group
        return previous + [[current]]
    } else {
        // add to existing group
        return previous.dropLast() + [last + [current]]
    }
}
```